# When I move apps to SD card, it said "App has stopped"

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, android-versions, google-apps

[image]

[image]

Everytime I move an app to SD card, it will say "App has stopped" and the icon changes.
I keep on retrying to uninstall and install it again and again, but it's still the same.
I don't want to lose my data again.

I bought this phone last year.

```
Device: Samsung Galaxy V
Model: SM-G313HZ
Android version: 4.2.2 (KitKat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you unmount an SD Card (internal or external) before selecting "Move to SD card? After unmounting an external SD card on Android 4.4.2, I selected "Move to SD card" on an app (because I had an internal SD card). I was told `com.unity.3d.UnityNativePlayer had stopped`.

The solution is to reboot. Your SD card will be automatically remounted, and apps will function normally.